# url automatically encoding when using file_get_contents php?

Tags: php

When i tried to get image from url `http://example.com/img.jpg?aa=11&bb=22` using `file_get_contents()` function, the url encoded to `http://example.com/img.jpg?aa=11&amp;bb=22`.

And it showing an error `file_get_contents(http://example.com/img.jpg?aa=11&amp;bb=22) : failed to open stream: Connection timed out in filename.php`

How can i avoid this url encoding?

my code is

```
$imgurl = "http://example.com/img.jpg?aa=11&bb=22";
file_get_contents($imgurl);
```

Comment: That would only happen if you call `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`. Post your code.

Comment: @Barmar i have added my code.  please help me

Comment: I don't see anything to help with, that should work. Are you really setting `$imgurl` like that, or are you getting it from a database, URL parameter, etc.?

Comment: its getting from facebook api via javascript and passing to php using jquery ajax. but i have printed the url in php. that is like the above url format. encoded url is showing only in error.@Barmar

Comment: When you print in PHP into a web page, the entities get decoded by the browser, so you're not seeing exactly what you're getting back from the API. Show your Javascript code.

Comment: $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 data:{img:imgurl},
 url: "test.php", 
 success: function(result){
  $("#div1").html(result);
 }});
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139396/discussion-between-riyas-pk-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the encoding is coming from, but you can decode it with `html_entity_decode()`:

```
$imgurl = html_entity_decode($_POST['img']);
```

Comment: same problem there when decoding. i thing this encoding in side the file_get_contents()

Comment: I've never heard of `file_get_contents` doing that. It makes no sense for it to do it.